# How can I properly use pipe and currying in F#?

Tags: f#, functional-programming, .net-core

I'm reading about F# and trying to apply it to my daily job.
I was already been able to load a CSV file with the help of `FSharp.Data` from NuGet, but I did it a imperative style, I think. Now I'm trying to apply functional constructs, tried the following:

```
open System
open System.IO
open FSharp.Data

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
  let data =
    argv.[0]
    |> Path.Combine Environment.CurrentDirectory
    |> CsvFile.Load

  printfn "%A" data.Headers

  0
```

What I'm missing here?
In my head `argv.[0]` is passed to the result of `Path.Combine Environment.CurrentDirectory` which curried already have the current dir as the first `path` then the combined result is given to `CsvFile.Load`.
Did I get `|>` and curring wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `Path.Combine` is a C# function which takes a `params` array, you cannot pipe parameters into the non-zero positions.  You can create an array and pass that instead:

```
[|Environment.CurrentDirectory; argv.[0]|]
|> Path.Combine
|> CsvFile.Load
```

Comment: Thank you! That was it. .NET functions receives tuples and can't be curried

    (Environment.CurrentDirectory, argv.[0])
      |> Path.Combine
      |> CsvFile.Load

Answer (score 1):

Your pipeline looks correct, so I suspect that your issue is that `CsvFile.Load` [is documented to take a URI, not a filename](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/reference/fsharp-data-csvfile.html). To check whether you're getting the right filename, I would first replace `CsvFile.Load` with `printfn "Got result: %s"` in your pipeline to check whether you're getting the filename you expect. Then if it is what you expect (and I think it will be), you can add another step to the pipeline:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
  let data =
    argv.[0]
    |> Path.Combine Environment.CurrentDirectory
    |> sprintf "file://%s"  // Convert filename to URI
    |> CsvFile.Load

  printfn "%A" data.Headers

  0
```

Since you're apparently new to F#, I'll expand those steps a little so you can confirm that your intuition is correct:

```
    argv.[0]
    |> Path.Combine Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

This is like calling `Path.Combine Environment.CurrentDirectory argv.[0]`.

```
    argv.[0]
    |> Path.Combine Environment.CurrentDirectory
    |> sprintf "file://%s"  // Convert filename to URI
```

This is like calling `sprintf "file://%s" (Path.Combine Environment.CurrentDirectory argv.[0])`.

```
    argv.[0]
    |> Path.Combine Environment.CurrentDirectory
    |> sprintf "file://%s"  // Convert filename to URI
    |> CsvFile.Load
```

This is like calling `CsvFile.Load (sprintf "file://%s" (Path.Combine Environment.CurrentDirectory argv.[0]))`.

From what you said in your question, it looks like this agrees with your understanding because you're understanding pipes correctly. So just pass `CsvFile.Load` a URI instead of a filename and you should be fine.

Comment: I think the issue is with piping into `Path.Combine`, which takes a `params` array.